# Combining TextContent and information from elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I combine text content and content of elements with jQuery?

```js
function getText(key, node) {
    if (node.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        return node.value;
    } else {
        return node.textContent;
    }
}

console.log($("div").find('*').map(getText).get().join(' ').trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <span>A</span>
 <div>
   B
   <input value='4'>
   <span>C</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

should be rendered to the string "A B 4 C".

It is no problem to get just the textContent with `.text()` or render the values of the input elements with `.map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(' ')` but getting both combined in the right order is difficult.

EDIT: The implementation should work on every depth of nesting elements. It is used to get a comparable output for unit testing parts of a web page where some visible texts like labels are rendered into span and other parts like editable values are in input elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: It'll involve a recursive function and detecting what kind of element you're dealing with (since you want to handle `input` [and perhaps `select`?] specially).

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the jQuery code. Please add it to your question by editing it :-)

Comment: so you want something like `content of the first span + content of the following div + value of the input field + content of the second span`?

Comment: @messerbill I edited the question. It should work on any structure and the decision if and what of an element is added to the result depends on the type of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with it you can just loop through all the elements in the top level `div` ignoring the text of child elements and append it to where you want it getting the text or value. Something like this

```js
$(".top *").each(function(){

    $(".holder").append($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text() || $(this).val());
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
 <span>A</span>
 <div>
   B
   <input value='4'>
   <span>C</span>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="holder">

</div>
```

NOTE: I added a class of `top` to the top level div to be able to select it

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is just to coalesce the values using an `OR` if the `val()` is something use it, otherwise get the `text()`.

```js
$(function() {
  var a = [];
  a = $.map($(".read *"), function(elem) {
    return $(elem).val() ||
           $(elem)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
  });
  console.log(a.join(" "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='read'>
  <span>A</span>
  <div>
    B
    <input value='4'>
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have problems running this example exactly as you have written because of the multiple jQuery roots and/or it is returning me addtional attributes like JavaScript attached to the elements. Beside of this as far as I understand your answer it is not working for arbitrary structures.

Comment: I modified the answer to iterate over all elements inside `.read`  I am not sure what you mean by returning additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

With the ideas of the others I created this answer. Perhaps it could be optimized in some way, but at least it works like expected.

```js
function getText(key, node) {
    if (node.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        return node.value;
    } else {
        let result = "";
        for(var child=node.firstChild; child!==null; child=child.nextSibling) {
            if (child.nodeType === 3) {
                result = result + " "+ child.nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

console.log($("div").find('*').map(getText).get().join(' ').trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <span>A</span>
 <div>
   B
   <input value='4'>
   <span>C</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: In fact it also doesn't work correctly if C is not inside of a span.